# KnexJS Using Array of Columns: "Unhandled rejection Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column"

Tags: mysql, sql, knex.js

We're using an array of column names in knex:

```
    knex
        .select( ["rowid", "accountid", "accountname"] )
        .from("account")
        .then(function (e, rows) {
            callback(e, rows)
    })
```

and getting the following error:

```
select `rowid,accountid,accountname` from `account`

Unhandled rejection Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'rowid,accountid,accountname' in 'field list'
```

Obviously the column name array has been converted to a string of fields which is causing the error. Using individual fields works correctly:

```
    knex
        .select( "rowid", "accountid", "accountname" )
        .from('account')
        .then(function (e, rows) {
            callback(e, rows)
    })
```

Is this a known issue? Is there a workaround for using an array with the 'select' function?

Comment: May I know why do you need to query by an array? Is it being passed from other function?

Comment: We keep our fields in a data dictionary. Also, the knex documentation indicates that this is allowed: "select.select([*columns]) 
Creates a select query, taking an optional array of columns for the query, eventually defaulting to * if none are specified when the query is built. The response of a select call will resolve with an array of objects selected from the database."

Comment: It looks like were stuck!. A string of fields does not work and an array does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide more detail? Database used, node/knex/db-driver versions... a simple test using knex 0.9.0, SQLite 3.1.4 and node 5.12 worked fine using column name arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a test using knex 0.9.0 and it accepted array arguments for `select` without complaining:

```
knex.
  select(['c1','t1','c2']).
  from('sample').
  then(function(rows) {
    console.dir(rows);
  });
// console.dir output:
// [ { c1: 22, t1: 'xx', c2: 33 },
//   { c1: 422, t1: 'xxxx', c2: 77 } ]
```

As you may have noticed your example has a problem anyway, `then()` does not follow the common callback error first style (`callback(error, result)`) but the opposite: `then(success_callback, failure_callback)`, with bluebird offering a convenience method `catch()` to avoid the failure call. So you may change your code to:

```
knex
  .select( ["rowid", "accountid", "accountname"] )
  .from('account')
  .then(function (rows) {
    callback(null, rows)
  })
  .catch(function (e) {
    callback(e, null);
  });
```

If you still happen to be using a version of knex that does not allow an array of column names you may replace the direct call by an `.apply()` call, like:

```
knex
  .select.apply(knex, ["rowid", "accountid", "accountname"] )
  .from('account')
  .then(function (rows) {
    callback(null, rows)
  })
  .catch(function (e) {
    callback(e, null);
  });
```